# createServer method in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, server

I've been looking over this basic example in order to set up a simple server in Node, however I am really struggling to understand where the 'request' and 'response' parameters are coming from. Where do they point to and how?

```
// Load the http module to create an http server.
var http = require('http');

function onRequest(request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.end("Hello World\n");
}

// Configure our HTTP server to respond with Hello World to all requests.
var server = http.createServer(onRequest);

// Listen on port 8000, IP defaults to 127.0.0.1
server.listen(8000);
```

Usually when passing paramaters into a function I pass something I can see, like a variable equal to 5, or 'Hello', but in this case I'm not...

Sorry if this is not explained very well!

Comment: They're coming from Node, and they point to the request and response objects created internally by Node.

Comment: And since you're not, you can assume something *else* is calling them, in this case, the `http` module you require.

Comment: And if you're extremely interested in figuring out exactly how Node creates those arguments from an incoming http call, you can read [the source](https://github.com/nodejs/node)

Comment: So when I create the server using the createServer method, that takes the callback function and sets those objects (response, request) to the data that is created upon a request to the server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you call `createServer`, you are passing the function `onRequest` to it:

```
var server = http.createServer(onRequest);
```

This pattern is known as a *callback*: you pass a function to someone else, with the expectation that they will call your function if something interesting has happened.

In essence, you are saying to Node,

> Hey, please create an HTTP server for me. Whenever you receive a request, call my function `onRequest` with the request and response objects passed as parameters.

Another way to do this is to listen to the [`request` event](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_request), which takes the same parameters in its callback.

The parameters are documented as being [`http.IncomingMessage`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_incomingmessage) and [`http.ServerResponse`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse). You can call them whatever you want, but `request` and `response` are the idiomatic parameter names. (Some people use `req` and `res` because they are shorter to type.)

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

Create server and send response :

1).Create server

```
    var http = require('http');
    var server = http.createServer ( function(request,response){
        response.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type":"text\plain"});
        response.end("Hello");
    });

    server.listen(8000);
    console.log("Server running on port 8000");
```

2).Save above code and run in cmd .

3).Open browser and go to http://localhost:8000/

Now you see the "Hello"